# ¿Cómo puedo insertar el registro del documento en la tabla del usuario y contraseña?

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando en un sistema donde hago un registro inicial de los empleados de la empresa,este registro solo lleva datos iniciales, como el **nombre** ,**documento**, quisiera saber cómo puedo guardar automáticamente el registro del documento como **usuario** y **contraseña** por defecto en otra tabla llamada acceso.
Ejemplo:

**Tabla empleado:**
documento=123

**Tabla acceso:** 
user=123   pass=123

Intente hacer esta inserción pero no funciona, obviamente debe tener muchos errores que no se cómo corregir,yo utilizo el `$this` por que trabajo con variables encapsuladas`(POO)`, estoy probando sin el `$this` a ver que sucede.

```
public  function insertarEmpleado(){


    $sql="INSERT  INTO empleado (documento)
         VALUES(

        '$this->documento',
        '$this->nombres',
        '$this->apellidos',
        '$this->celular',
        '$this->telefono',
        '$this->direccion',
        '$this->estado_civil',
        '$this->perfil',
        '$this->fecha_ingreso',
        '$this->fecha_nacimiento',
        '$this->foto')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO acceso (acce_id,acce_usuario,acce_clave,empl_doc)


 VALUES (


 '$this->documento',
 '$this->documento',
 '$this->documento',
 '$this->documento')";

    $insert=$this->db->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: Deberías publicar el código, así te podrían ayudar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes validarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "datos";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  //Consulto el documento del formulario
  $documento = $_POST['documento'];
  //Inserto en la base de datos empleado
  $sql = "INSERT INTO empleado (documento) VALUES 
  ('$documento')";
  //Inserto en la base de datos acceso
  $sql = "INSERT INTO acceso (usuario, contrasenia) VALUES 
  ('$documento','$documento')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

El secreto está en que al momento de registrar el **documento:123** en la tabla de *empleados*, puedes registrar con ese mismo **documento:123**, en la tabla de *accseo*, con el siguiente código.

```
//Inserto en la base de datos empleado
$sql = "INSERT INTO empleado (documento) VALUES ('$documento')";
//Inserto en la base de datos acceso
$sql = "INSERT INTO acceso (usuario, contrasenia) VALUES ('$documento','$documento')";
```

Espero te ayude!

Comment: Esto podria funconar,pero olvide mencionar que la tabla acceso debe generear un id tipo serial que obviamente no es el documento que viene de empleado,la tabla acceso tambien hereda el documento como llave foranea. como se podria general el serial y asignar automaticamente el usuario y contraseña

Comment: ¿Es decir que aparte del documento se sube un **id**, y el **id** es el user y la pass de acceso?

Comment: Se debe generar un id tipo serial en la tabla acceso, pero acceso hereda ese documento como llave foranea,ademas ese documento debe estar de forma automatica en  usuario y clave de la tabla acceso  para que despues el usuari lo modifique.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, puedes crear dos tablas. Puedes tomar estas de ejemplo, estan relacionadas 1:1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombres` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `documentos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `accesos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accesos` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `empleados_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `empleados_id`),
  INDEX `fk_accesos_empleados1_idx` (`empleados_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accesos_empleados1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`empleados_id`)
    REFERENCES `empleados` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Aqui tienes lo siguiente, la tabla **accesos** esta relacionada a la tabla **empleados**. Un **acceso** corresponde a un **empleado**, es decir, registras al empleado, obtienes el **id de ese registro** y lo insertas en la tabla accesos en el campo **empleados_id** con los demas datos. Este seria un ejemplo

```
INSERT INTO empleados(id,nombres,documentos) VALUES(NULL,'Pedro Perez','12345');
```

Esa inserción genera un ID autoincrementable para ese registro, supongamos que es **1**, insertarias en la tabla **accesos** de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO accesos(id,password,usuario,empleados_id) VALUES(NULL,'password','usuario',1);
```

En **PHP** debes hacer una ejecucion de query una por una y obtener el ultimo ID insertado. Es decir, registras al **empleado** y obtienes el **ID** de esa insercion. Te coloco un ejemplo directo de la documentación de PHP

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

?>